# Google Sheets - SPLIT SORT and JOIN only one column in a FILTER array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Adding SORT to this filter function is easy, but how do I sort alphabetically by the last name in Col2 with header "Name".

I think I want to SPLIT the names, then SORT after " ", then JOIN them back for the goal output.
**How do I SPLIT and JOIN only one column within the FILTER array, but still return the entire array?**

My function: =SORT(FILTER({'Flow 1'!$A$2:$H},'Flow 1'!$G$2:$G<28),2,TRUE)

Col2 is Name, So it would be SORT by Col3 after SPLIT.
Then JOIN?

I'm sure this is simple, I just don't know the right syntax. Or maybe I need different functions due to the limitations of SORT and SPLIT?

SS url:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13UrhhJbNsDMNlY7GN-8oELpKfxJhT9a486GndGkq-2k/edit#gid=400517389

Share link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13UrhhJbNsDMNlY7GN-8oELpKfxJhT9a486GndGkq-2k/edit?usp=sharing

I'm just trying to sort the array in SBF tab by last name. That's all.
Some names do have more than two words, so it will need to be by the last word in the name.

TIA

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I'll have to make a new one to demo the issue. Original has sensitive customer info. Just a sec.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(FILTER({'Flow 1'!A2:H, REGEXEXTRACT('Flow 1'!B2:B, "\w*$")}, 
             'Flow 1'!G2:G<28,
             'Flow 1'!G2:G>1E-16,
  REGEXMATCH('Flow 1'!C2:C, "SBF"),
  REGEXMATCH('Flow 1'!D2:D, "Tuesday|Wednesday")), 9, 1), 9^9, 8)
```

[image]